# Python: Get top level class

Tags: python

I want to build in some dummy checks, so that for some methods only equal top level classes are used and I was wondering if this was the way to do it:

```
class A:
    def func(self, x):
        if self.__class__.__mro__[-2] == x.__class__.__mro__[-2]:
            print("OK!")

class B(A): pass

ins_a = A()
ins_b = B()

ins_a.func(x=ins_b)
```

In principle I just want to make sure, that a method does not get called when the input `x` in `func` is not of the same class (or inherited). The `.__mro__[-2]` operator always gives me the top level class, and the method obviously works. I was just not sure if this is considered ok programming and whether there is another solution.

thanks

Comment: What *exactly* are you trying to check? Why not just use `isinstance`?

Comment: Ah, exactly what I wanted to hear, so the if line changes to 
if isinstance(x,A)

I just want to make sure, that whenever func is called, that x must also be of class A (or B which inherits A)

thanks!!

Comment: "I just want to make sure, that a method does not get called when the input" - when the input *what*?

Comment: @HansSnah: yes, that is what `isinstance()` would correctly test for.

Comment: @user2357112: Sorry, I hope its more clear now. Anyway, I have got the answer I was looking for  thanks to all!

Answer (score -1):

Use `type(x).__bases__` - that's a tuple of parents of `x`'s ancestors, and when that has only one element (object), `x` is an object of a top-level class.

Comment: `type(x).__mro__` is a complete list of all ancestors, not just limited to direct bases.

Comment: Yeah, apparently I didn't understand the question. I thought that OP wanted to make sure that `x` is an instance of `A`, but not any derived class (it was the "only top level class" sentence that confused me :)